# Error reading XML via JaxB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

This is my class structure:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="System")
public class SystemDTO () {

  @XmlElement(name="ID")
  public void setId(String id) {
      this.id = id;
  }

  @XmlElement(name="Source")
  public void setSource(SourceDTO source) {
      this.source = source;
  }
}

@XmlRootElement(name="Source")
class SourceDTO {
  @XmlElement(name="Name")
  public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
  }
}
```

This is my XML File:

```
<System>
   <ID>e5b160d0</ID>
   <Source>
     <Name>Kron</Name>
   </Source>
</System>
```

The problem is the Source is always null.  I do not get a exception, it just comes out null.  I've attempted to use just the Source tag and it picks up Name just fine, but when I add it as part of the System class it does not seem to work.

Additionally I attempted to do this and have a string member variable in System for name:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="Source")
@XmlElement(name="Name")
```

But that causes an exception.  Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `@XmlRootElement` from the `SourceDTO` class?

Comment: I just tried that and it is still null.

Comment: I just fixed your class `public class SystemDTO {` added public getters and it works fine

Comment: Kenneth could you provide an answer by posting code?  I left the getters out for brevity.

Comment: @PeteBelford nothing obvious wrong that i can see, posted my code below

Comment: @PeteBelford Strange. I used your code without the getters and it worked for me. I had to add the fields of course. But I guess you have solved your problem now, so it doesn't matter. It might be how you unmarshalled the xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Test Class

```
    public class JaxbTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            String xml = "<System>\n" +
                    "   <ID>e5b160d0</ID>\n" +
                    "   <Source>\n" +
                    "     <Name>Kron</Name>\n" +
                    "   </Source>\n" +
                    "</System>";
            SystemDTO systemDTO;
            try {

                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(SystemDTO.class);

                StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
                Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                systemDTO = (SystemDTO) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
                System.out.println(systemDTO.getSource().getName());

            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Source DTO

```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "Source")
    class SourceDTO {
        private String name = null;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        @XmlElement(name = "Name")
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

    }
```

System DTO

```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "System")
    public class SystemDTO {

        private String id;
        private SourceDTO source;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public SourceDTO getSource() {
            return source;
        }

        @XmlElement(name = "ID")
        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @XmlElement(name = "Source")
        public void setSource(SourceDTO source) {
            this.source = source;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  Of course I edited my actual source code to simplify the problem, but was able to build your example back up to what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem that I see is that you have declared 2 "Root" elements in your XML. Try @XmlType on your Source class:

```
    @XmlType(name="Source")
    class SourceDTO {
       ...
    }
```

Comment: Tried this it still came up null.  In other classes I did not have a problem with this.